# What to put in msg.criteria for fetching emails in Node-RED email node?

Tags: node-red

I have two flows using the `node-red-node-email` node in Node-RED.

The first one uses predefined value for fetching all emails (**Criteria**: **All**). It works properly and fetches two emails I have in my Inbox:

[image: flow 1]

The second one should emulate the same, but thru specifying `msg.criteria`:

I created a flow with a `change` node setting the value.

The info page for the email module refers to a [doc page for another module](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/blob/master/README.md#connection-instance-methods) and does not give a clear example, but I assumed I should add a string value of `[ ALL ]`. Here's the relevant part of the `change` module:

```
"rules": [
    {
        "t": "set",
        "p": "criteria",
        "pt": "msg",
        "to": "[ 'ALL' ]",
        "tot": "str"
    }
```

In result the email node changes to `connecting` then to `fetching` and remains in this state. The Node-RED web server does not respond for a while.

[image: flow 2]

I also tried specifying `msg.criteria` as a JSON object the following way (in result I get an `"Invalid 'to' JSON property"` in debug):

```
"rules": [
    {
        "t": "set",
        "p": "criteria",
        "pt": "msg",
        "to": "[ 'ALL' ]",
        "tot": "json"
    }
],
```

or the following way (in result I have no response at all; the email node does not even go to `connecting` state):

```
"rules": [
    {
        "t": "set",
        "p": "criteria",
        "pt": "msg",
        "to": "{ [ 'ALL' ] }",
        "tot": "json"
    }
],
```

What type should `msg.criteria` be and what data should it contain to fetch all emails (and by extension other criteria)?

Comment: The email node expects `msg.criteria` to be a string not JSON. Try with ` [ 'UNSEEN' ]` instead of `[ 'ALL' ]` then it should just return new mail, rather than your entire inbox (which could be huge).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So `msg.criteria` was a string in my first example which did not work. I used `[ALL]` here to avoid comments about `[UNSEEN]` fetching only unread messages. As you can see on the first screenshot, I have two emails in my inbox so it's not an issue. They are fetched with Criteria field set to *All* but not fetched with Criteria set to *- set from msg.criteria -* and `msg.criteria` set to `['ALL']`.

Comment: OK, I've been back and looked at the source some more, the earlier comment is wrong. `msg.criteria` should be a JSON array (the bit where the internal versions are converted from a string to an array is very subtle). The problem you saw is also very subtle to do with quote types in the change node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my second comment, this is most likely to do with how you set up the change node with the JSON array.

The following change node config works as expected.

[image]

Note that `ALL` is wrapped with double quotes, not single quotes. This is important as the Change node throws an error when single quotes are set and doesn't actually add the field to the `msg` object.

Comment: Oh, that's crazy. All the referenced docs show `[ 'ALL' ]` etc. in single quotes, though, for a different purpose. Thank you.

Comment: is a way to add condition like `startsWith` ?